# Adding Swagger UI to Angular App

Tags: angular, swagger-ui

Is there a good way to add the [Swagger UI](https://swagger.io/docs/swagger-tools/#swagger-ui-documentation-29) to an Angular app without getting too much in the weeds?

I'd like to add a reference to an API which is hosted on a different site, so all I need is the UI elements to reference the docs.

I found a package called [Swangular-Components](https://npmdaily.com/pkg/swangular-components), but it seems to mess up my index.d.ts file. A solution like that would be the simplest for my situation, I think.

Comment: This repo shows how to use the Swagger UI Node Module within an Angular app https://github.com/agoncal/swagger-ui-angular6

Comment: I found a good way by adding it to the express server

Answer (score 10):

I've struggled with this numerous times but finally figured out somewhat of a solution mainly because I stumbled across this issue of adding swagger-editor to an angular project (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57431950/5641007). Had to tweak it a bit for swagger ui but ultimately got it working.

Install swagger-ui-dist

`npm install swagger-ui-dist --save`

Configure the angular.json file and desired component for swagger-ui.

```
// angular.json

"styles": [
    "node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css",
    "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-bundle.js",
    "node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"
]
```

```
// component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare const SwaggerUIBundle: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-swagger-ui',
  templateUrl: './swagger-ui.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./swagger-ui.component.css']
})
export class SwaggerUiComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
      layout: 'BaseLayout',
      presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
      ],
      url: 'https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json',
      docExpansion: 'none',
      operationsSorter: 'alpha'
    });
  }
}
```

```
// component.html

<div id="swagger-ui"></div>
```

Github repo for example app: 
https://github.com/ostranme/angular-swagger-ui-example

Comment: I've done the same and got the error 'SwaggerUIBundle is not defined'. Could you, please, help me?

Comment: I have the same error as @IlyaBerdzenishvili. Did you guys manage to get a solution?

Comment: it's working for me, but don't forget to restart your 'ng serve' after editing the 'angular.json'

Answer (score 2):

This is 8 months old now so I'm assuming you figured it out or moved on, but it's possible to do this in a basic, if not ideal, way using Renderer2. You'd basically create a script element containing the config for swagger-ui and a link to the external doc, then use Renderer2 to append the tag to your component. I'm using this now as a way to embed the swagger-ui in an angular app that allows the user to choose between different api docs.