# Angular: add Swagger UI

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, swagger-ui

I'm working with the **Angular 10**. I've created classic skeleton of angular app and now i'd like to add **swagger-ui** component to my app.

Firstly, i've found the following lovely example https://github.com/agoncal/swagger-ui-angular6 and changed my app according the example. But after it my app has failed during the compilation:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:2:23 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'swagger-ui'. 'some/path/to/my/app/node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/swagger-ui` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'swagger-ui';`
```

Also I've found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58514408/7888743 and done it all, but after startup i got the error in browser console:

```
SwaggerUI is not defined
```

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the Swagger logic in ngAfterViewInt() ?
Because I got it to work in my case